# Indentation of line numbers while using equations within algorithm2e

Tags: indentation, algorithm2e, line-numbering

I have written some algorithms using the package `algorithm2e`. Some of my algorithms also include aligned formulas. My problem is that line numbers below lines ending with equations have a larger indent than the other line numbers. I'd like to have all line numbers aligned. How can I accomplish that?

I use pdflatex.

A minimal working example with what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{: }{end}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \caption{Test algorithm}
    \label{alg:test}
    \Input{$i$.}
    \Output{$x$.}
    Set
    \begin{align*}
        i &\coloneqq i+1, \\
        j &\coloneqq i^2.
    \end{align*}%
    \nl Set $x \coloneqq j$.
\end{algorithm}
%
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \caption{Test algorithm 2}
    \label{alg:test2}
    \Input{$i$.}
    \Output{$x$.}
    Set
    \begin{algomathdisplay}
        \begin{aligned}
            i &\coloneqq i+1, \\
            j &\coloneqq i^3. \;
        \end{aligned}
    \end{algomathdisplay}
    Set $x \coloneqq j$. \;
\end{algorithm}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

The `algomathdisplay` environment doesn't really work: adding `\nl` at the end shifts the line number, `\;` adds a blank line.

Using directly `align*` is out of the question, as it produces too large space.

I can propose a patch that uses `\;` *and* removes the blank line.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{algomathdisplay}
 {\[}
 {\@endalgocfline\vspace{-\baselineskip}\]\;}
\makeatother


\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{: }{end}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \caption{Test algorithm 2}
    \label{alg:test2}
    \Input{$i$.}
    \Output{$x$.}
    Set
    \begin{algomathdisplay}
        \begin{aligned}
            i &\coloneqq i+1, \\
            j &\coloneqq i^3.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{algomathdisplay}
    Set $x \coloneqq j$.
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tested it both with and without `linesnumbered`.

Comment: If `\DontPrintSemicolon` is not used, this produces a stray semicolon after the equation. This can be fixed by replacing `\;` in your definition with `\hfill\strut\par`, see the definition of `\@endalgoln` (which is used in `\;`).

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the indent can be solved by removing `\nl` and adding a `\;` add the end of the first line. For the second case a patch of the `algomathdisplay` seems necessary.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled,algochapter,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\DontPrintSemicolon

\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{: }{end}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{algomathdisplay}{%
    \[%
    }{%
    \@endalgocfline%
    \]%
    %\ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@linesnumbered}}{\nl}{\relax}% <- in the original .sty
    }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \caption{Test algorithm}
    \label{alg:test}
    \Input{$i$.}
    \Output{$x$.}
    Set
    \begin{align*}
        i &\coloneqq i+1, \\
        j &\coloneqq i^2.
    \end{align*}\;
    Set $x \coloneqq j$.
\end{algorithm}
%
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \caption{Test algorithm 2}
    \label{alg:test2}
    \Input{$i$.}
    \Output{$x$.}
    Set%
    \begin{algomathdisplay}
        \begin{aligned}
            i &\coloneqq i+1, \\
            j &\coloneqq i^3.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{algomathdisplay}\;
    Set $x \coloneqq j$. \;
\end{algorithm}
%
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]