# Correct usage of algomathdisplay in algorithm2e

Tags: math-mode, algorithm2e

What is the correct usage of `algomathdisplay` from the `algorithm2e` package? I appear to have misunderstood its usage, see example below. There are two different attempts one with just

```latex
\begin{algomathdisplay}
   ...
\end{algomathdisplay}
%
next line
```

which causes weird indentations on the next line, and a second attempt:

```latex
\begin{algomathdisplay}
   ...
\end{algomathdisplay}\;
%
next line
```

which results in an empty semicolon-line

[image]

lastly here is the full code

```latex
\begin{algorithm}
    \While{test}{
        Some words introducing the following equation
        \begin{algomathdisplay}
            1+1
        \end{algomathdisplay}
        Another line\;
        Words introducing the second equation
        \begin{algomathdisplay}
            2+2
        \end{algomathdisplay}\;
        Last Line;
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

### Wrong Solutions

Suggested Macro fix by  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543384/82917

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{algomathdisplay}
 {\[}
 {\@endalgocfline\vspace{-\baselineskip}\]\;}
\makeatother

\begin{algorithm}
    \While{test}{
        Another line\;
        Words introducing the second equation
        \begin{algomathdisplay}
            2+2
        \end{algomathdisplay}
        Last Line\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: @campa thanks for the comment - so I guess this *should* work in normal circumstances? Because I just assumed I made an immediately obvious user error.

Comment: @campa yeah sorry - fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the global `\DontPrintSemicolon` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/543384/82917

something less invasive can be achieved with

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{algomathdisplay}
 {\[}
 {\@endalgocfline\vspace{-\baselineskip}\]{\DontPrintSemicolon\;}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for!